# send comma separated some array generated in a loop in php and laravel

Tags: php, laravel

suppose we have an Object that accept some value as array that is separated by comma:

```
$keyboard = new Keyboard(
            ['value1'],
            ['value2'],
            ['value3'],
            ['value4']
        );
```

Now I want to fetch some value from database via a loop and send them finally to that object. but I do not know how can I collect them and send a comma separated list of them.

I write this code But can not get appropriate result from it:

```
$brands = Option::with('translations')->whereHas('attribute', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('type', '=', 'brand');
                })->get();

                $titles = [];
                foreach ($brands as $key => $brand) {
                    $titles [] = array($brand->title_fa);
                }

                $keyboard = new Keyboard(
                    $titles
                );
```

Comment: Hi, it's not clear your intention, Keyboard class is receive a single array argument?, are you using `varidic` params to receive an N number arguments? or are you receiving an string comma separated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `...` operator to pass parameters. But check before whether size of an array is proper.

```
$keyboard = new Keyboard(...$titles);
```

Answer (score 1):

First I suggest plucking the value that you want and then map them

Look at the Laravel Collection methods to avoid doing unnecessary loops and doing it more fluent

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections

```
$brands = Option::with('translations')->whereHas('attribute', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('type', '=', 'brand');
                })->get()
                  ->pluck('title_fa')
                  ->map(function($brand){ return [$brand]; })->all()
```

Now you have a `$brands` array as required

So you can pass it as an array or as a [Varidic params](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new) using the Splat operator as suggested in the other answer

```
$keyboard = new Keyboard($brands);
$keyboard = new Keyboard(...$brands);
```